# Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: badlogic.jpg

Tags: java, android, eclipse, libgdx

i'm begginer programmer and need some help. I'm using eclipse and libgdx. I created a project. When i try to load my file "background.png", i get this error:

> "Exception in thread "LWJGL Application"
>   com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file:
>   badlogic.jpg"

. Oh wait, did you see that ? My file's name is "background.png", and error tells me that couldn't load "badlogic.jpg" I searched many forums but didnt find the solution cuz i think im the only one who is getting this error. And dont worry i have written my code correctly.`

This is GameScreen method

```
Reaction game;
OrthographicCamera camera;
SpriteBatch batch;


public GameScreen(Reaction game){
    this.game = game;

    camera=new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(true,1920,1080);

    batch = new SpriteBatch();

}

@Override
public void show() {

}

@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.95F, 0.95F, 0.95F, 0.95F);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    camera.update(); 
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
        batch.draw(Assets.sprite_back,0,0);
    batch.end();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {

}

@Override
public void pause() {

}

@Override
public void resume() {

}

@Override
public void hide() {

}

@Override
public void dispose() {

}

}
```

this is Assets method

```
public static Texture texture_back;
public static Sprite sprite_back;

    public static void load(){

        texture_back= new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/background.png"));
        texture_back.setFilter(TextureFilter.Linear,TextureFilter.Linear);
        sprite_back=new Sprite(texture_back);
        sprite_back.setFlip(false, true);
    }
}
```

and this is main game method

```
public GameScreen game_screen;

@Override
public void create() {
    Assets.load();
    game_screen = new GameScreen(this);

    setScreen(game_screen);

}

}
```

I'm sure my code is correct cuz i made it with getting help from youtube videos. Please help me, im stuck...

More information: my files are linked, when i put my png file to assets/data folder it appears in desktop's assets too, and eclipse also automatically refresh files and when i manage files on eclipse, it happens to real project folder in my desktop, i tried to make it for you easier, i wish it helps.

Comment: didnt work cuz it is already like that

Comment: as i said, didnt work

Comment: think I should put some more of code

Comment: ok i will put more, sec. But im very begginner in java, so dont expect much :)

Comment: if that's all code? that code is not what is running, try putting `Gdx.app.log (" test "," test "); somewhere to run for example in method create before  Asset.load, to see if it really is that the code that is running

Comment: this is not all code, i just put some parts of it, i mean necessary parts. code was running before i change images, the old code was created by libgdx and it had badlogic.jpg then i changed it with mine, then it messed up...

Comment: has several options, look at the code looking for a call to load badlogic.jpg somewhere, create a new project and add the parts you want, assuming it is the code which is really ejecuntando and none other, "although it may be some strange error "but I think that is not the case but it is just my opinion P.S: copy the image baglogic.jpg in asset for test

Comment: Have you tried cleaning your project?